# Управление возвращаемым результатом mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Возможно ли что либо сделать, для того чтобы по запросу в базу данных mysql в возвращаемом результате были не все столбцы?
Точнее все кроме одного, перечисление возвращаемых столбцов не вариант так как их количество может меняться, следовательно придется менять сам запрос.

Comment: Да это возможно

Comment: "SELECT  id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests",  Пишите Select потом пишите столбцы которые вам нужны, если нужны все укажите *

Comment: @Даниил как автоматизировать можно? На случай изменения количества столбцов? Как вернут все кроме первого?

Comment: Ну выводите в запросе все столбцы, а программно указывайте какой нужно вывести какой нет.

Comment: Вот статья есть, посмотрите почитайте. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Вы можете выводить нужный столбец например вот так в PHP:  echo "id: " . $row["id"];

Comment: Спасибо за статью и вариант, я понял что это проще сделать программно foreach ($result as $k => $v) { if($k != 'id') { $arr[$k] = $v } }. Это костыль?)

Comment: Напишиите в вопросе суть задачи,вам напишут более точный вопрос если вы не знаете как это делать.

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, mysql в себе содержит кучу служебной информации. Например запрос `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME LIKE \'prefix%\''` вернет наименование таблиц, столбцов и их тип по префиксу имен таблиц. У меня результат закеширован. Меняю я его только при изменении структуры таблиц. Использую для построения запросов к базе (например, для сохранения только измененных полей модели).